# Model validation based on the DataType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project, with a classic 3 tier structure: DataStore, BusinessLogic, Web-Frontend

In the DataStore I have a Model (simplified) e.g. ConfigModel.cs:

```
public class ConfigModel
{

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string DefaultSenderEmail { get; set; }

    public IPAddress FallbackDNS { get; set; }

}
```

Here comes the question:

**What's an elegant way to programmatically add Validators according to either the actual DataType, or the DataType Attribute?**

A few answers that I have considered myself so far, but did not find them satisfactory:

- Add an [EmailAddress] validation attribute to the parameter: I don't want duplication and I don't want any reference to MVC specific code in my DataStore Layer.
- Make separate ViewModels and use AutoMapper: Since some of my models are a lot more complex than that, I'd hate to make specific ViewModels.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer but do have some advice. It might be a good idea to look into using ViewModels to restrict what data you are sending back and forth between the view and controller. This is an article about a possible vulnerability in MVC that you can protect yourself against, so long as you write an appropriate ViewModel: http://freshbrewedcode.com/joshbush/2012/03/05/mass-assignment-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider using AutoMapper, but not as an answer to this solution.

Maybe you can consider this: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/15/adding-client-validation-to-dataannotations-datatype-attribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is not duplication. DataType is used for different purposes, and validation is different thing. Although they may sound the same (specifically for EmailAddress), you should not consider using both as duplication. Moreover, validation is automatically controlled for non nullable types - they are marked as `Required`. Datetimes are also checked for valid format automatically.

What you will definitely hate is controlling what properties of your domain model can be edited by users using [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx) and controlling different validations on same model, when using different views. So go for using ViewModels! Decorate them with all the attributes needed for your web application and map back to domain models using `AutoMapper`

You also may also want to check out [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)